# TemplateNotFound Exception in Apache Ofbiz in Debug mode from Eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ofbiz

I configure apache ofbiz in debug mode using the second method titled **Debugging (or running) OFBiz inside Eclipse** from [this guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse). I have repeated the same procedure on windows and Ubuntu. In windows, ofbiz runs fine without problems and I can use it from browser on https://localhost:8443/ordermgr/control/main. But when I follow the same guide and try to run ofbiz from Ubuntu (16.0.4), I get the TemplateNotfound exception which is thrown from `RequestHandler.java` at line 989. Here is the stack trace

```
Communication error with the client while processing the request: /webtools/control/ServiceList
org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Error in the response writer/output stream: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@38cfbab5, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })). (Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@38cfbab5, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })).)
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.renderView(RequestHandler.java:989) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.doRequest(RequestHandler.java:649) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doGet(ControlServlet.java:210) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:209) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:156) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@38cfbab5, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })).
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2430) ~[freemarker-2.3.24-incubating.jar:2.3.24]
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2232) ~[freemarker-2.3.24-incubating.jar:2.3.24]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.getTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:259) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.getTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:253) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenRenderer.<init>(MacroScreenRenderer.java:84) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenViewHandler.loadRenderers(MacroScreenViewHandler.java:113) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenViewHandler.render(MacroScreenViewHandler.java:152) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.renderView(RequestHandler.java:985) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    ... 31 more
```

Any ideas why I get this error in Ubuntu?

Comment: I shared a more accurate solution to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121122/apache-ofbiz-execution-issues/52100051#52100051).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly the problem was but I was opening the ofbiz project from a different location than eclipse workspace and containing directory name was different than project name. I did the following to get it working

1. Deleted the project from eclipse
2. Moved the project directory to workspace
3. Renamed the project directory to match project name (ofbiz)
4. Opened it from eclipse
5. Followed [the guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse) to debug/run as mentioned in my question
   and all was suddenly working