# Apache OfBiz Execution issues

Tags: java, apache, ofbiz

Working with OfBiz on a 64-bit Win 7 machine and after I perform a fresh build, when the build is completed and I try to open any of the pages, my browser (both IE and Chrome) are blank. Any ideas?

OfBiz version 16.11.01

Snippet from the current log:

```
    |W| Communication error with the client while processing the request: /webtools/control/main
org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Error in the response writer/output stream: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@6e5ece55, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })). (Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@6e5ece55, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })).)
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.renderView(RequestHandler.java:989) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.doRequest(RequestHandler.java:649) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doGet(ControlServlet.java:210) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:209) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:156) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-catalina-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util-8.0.37.jar:8.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "component://widget/templates/HtmlScreenMacroLibrary.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker$FlexibleTemplateLoader@6e5ece55, loader2 = StringTemplateLoader(Map { })).
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2430) ~[freemarker-2.3.24-incubating.jar:2.3.24]
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2232) ~[freemarker-2.3.24-incubating.jar:2.3.24]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.getTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:259) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.template.FreeMarkerWorker.getTemplate(FreeMarkerWorker.java:253) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenRenderer.<init>(MacroScreenRenderer.java:84) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenViewHandler.loadRenderers(MacroScreenViewHandler.java:113) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.macro.MacroScreenViewHandler.render(MacroScreenViewHandler.java:152) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.renderView(RequestHandler.java:985) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Can you please provide details about how you are building your OfBiz project.

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834660/templatenotfound-exception-in-apache-ofbiz-in-debug-mode-from-eclipse-ubuntu, it's reporting the same missing .ftl file.

Comment: @RenéScheibe so, followed the steps verbatim from the website:
https://ofbiz.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out the issue. I had moved the entire directory into my C:\Program Files directory which due to corporate admin restrictions was likely blocking permissions somewhere. That being said, I moved the directory to a 'normal' location, re-ran gradlew and I can navigate to the pages. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Check via the DevTools in Chrome what's the HTTP status code of the response and the page content if there is any. You can see it in the [network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference) in the column "status".

Check the OfBiz log files for any errors or stacktraces.

Comment: What is the method to capture the HTTP status code of the response and page content?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the problem could be somewhere else. 
When you store your ofbiz application under a folder with space inside, the common visual theme don't work. So the solution is to either change the current top-parent folder by **erasing spaces** within its name, or **changing the folder** (you did it without knowing exactly what was going exactly).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i also face the same issue with OfBiz version 16.11.04 because of some admin side permission for the solution you need to put your project in c drive and start it. for me its working fine.